# Where in kernel/socket memory to store long term information between network sessions

Tags: memory-management, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

I'm trying to implement the QUIC protocol in the **linux kernel**. QUIC works on top of UDP to provide a connection-oriented, reliable data transfer.
QUIC was designed to reduce the number of handshakes required between sessions as compared to TCP.

Now, I need to store some data from my current QUIC session so that I can use it when the session ends and later on use it to initiate a new session. I'm at a loss about where should this data be stored so that it's not deleted between sessions.

**EDIT 1:** The data needs to be stored till the socket lives in the memory. Once the socket has been destroyed, I don't need the data anymore.

As an aside, how can I store data even between different sockets? Just need a general answer to this as I don't need it for now.

Thank you.

Comment: Additional info needed:  Does it _ever_ expire?  Does it need to survive reboots?  Is this data only at the initiating end, or do both the ends have data to hold on to?  What OS?

Comment: Are you free to modify socket code?

Comment: Yes, of course, as I'm working with the kernel source. I however would like to make only those changes that don't break the existing functionality.